# How Do I Get The offsetHeight of a Component Element in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a component using Vue.js, and inserting it into the DOM without any problems. Once the element is in the DOM, I'd like to know its rendered height - i.e., I'd like to get its *offsetHeight*. I can't work out how to do it - I must be missing something really obvious. This is what I've tried:

The HTML:

```
<!-- vue instance -->
<div id="my-app">

    <my-component></my-component>

</div>

<!-- component template -->
<template id="my-component">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    <pre>{{ myheight }}</pre>
</template>
```

The Vue Javascript:

```
Vue.component('my-component',{
    template: '#my-component',
    computed: {
        myheight: function(){
            return this.offsetHeight;
        }
    }
});

Vue({ el: '#my-app' });
```

But it doesn't work - 'myheight' ends up empty. I thought that maybe the problem was that it might have been trying to generate the computed property before it had been inserted into the DOM, so instead of using a computed property I tried this:

```
Vue.component('my-component',{
    template: '#my-component',
    data: function(){
        return {
            myheight: 999
        };
    },
    ready: function(){
        this.myheight = this.offsetHeight;
    }
});
```

Again, it doesn't work - it outputs nothing - and I don't get any errors or warnings in the console.

Then, I thought that maybe `this` was not an HTMLElement, so I searched the Vue documentation, and found that all Vue instances should have an `$el` property that points to the HTMLElement - or at least that's how I understood it... So I tried using `this.$el.offsetHeight` in both examples above, but again with no success.

Can someone point me in the right direction? All assistance is appreciated...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the issue lies in your template. You seem to have a [fragment instance](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance), meaning that you don't have a top level element that surrounds all the children.

So instead of this, where `$el` is likely not to refer to what you want…

```
<!-- component template -->
<template id="my-component">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    <pre>{{ myheight }}</pre>
</template>
```

…you could wrap your component in a parent element:

```
<!-- component template -->
<template id="my-component">
    <div class="my-component">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> <!-- and close the tag correctly -->
        <pre>{{ myheight }}</pre>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then you can get the offset-height using `this.$el.offsetHeight`:

```
Vue.component('my-component',{
    template: '#my-component',
    data: function(){
        return {
            myheight: 999
        };
    },
    ready: function(){
        this.myheight = this.$el.offsetHeight;
    }
});

new Vue({ el: '#my-component' });
```

Comment: Absolutely right - I knew it would be something obvious! Thank you!