# how to get element height in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, offsetheight

i'm trying to get offsetHeight of element but i got undefined.

with this i get html collection and everything works right:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("plyr--full-ui");
```

[image]

but if i add `.offsetHeight` i got undefined.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("plyr--full-ui").offsetHeight;
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Get The offsetHeight of a Component Element in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383422/how-do-i-get-the-offsetheight-of-a-component-element-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 1):

HTMLCollection is array-like object. This will get first element offsetHeight:

`document.getElementsByClassName("plyr--full-ui")[0].offsetHeight;`

Comment: i got this error: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined

Comment: i'm using nuxt, is this error related to ssr? i wrote this code in mounted hook.

Comment: I don't think it's related. The error basically means that JS can't find an element with a class name "plyr--full-ui" and returns undefined. Then you call offsetHeight on an undefined property, hence the error.